# Can I conserve the default this by using Function.bind ? If no, why?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs

Let's say I have a function :

```
function onSomethingChanged(field, evt) {
    this.validate(field, evt.target.value);
}
```

And I have a React component where I do :

```
<input onChanged={this.onSomethingChanged.bind(null, "username")} />
```

1. Does my `this` is conserved if I pass `null` as thisArg ?
2. If not, how could I conserve it without using explicitly `this` (without writing `this.onSomethingChanged.bind(this, "username")`).
3. If not **(again)**, why JavaScript prevent that? Is there a workaround?

Thanks !

Comment: Add react tag maybe?

Comment: If you mean the js library React then it should be tagged ReactJS, the tag you have used is for the php library of the same name.

Comment: Why is #2 an issue? It's very typical to see in JavaScript code if you're not using a closure and want to preserve the context correctly.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I may end up write this too much times, I'm okay to write this one time, but writing two times in the same line, isn't this too much "un-DRY"?

Comment: If it's not exactly the same function call, it's not really repeated, is it? If it is, then just create a local var with the result of calling `bind` and pass that.

Comment: No, but it's "trivial repetition", writing five times a call to a function with just one static arg is quite un-DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, context (`this`) of the function will be `null` in [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and global object (`window`) in `non-strict` mode

If you don't like `bind` approach you can use ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to handle this:

```
<input onChanged={()=>this.onSomethingChanged("username")} />
```

or if you don't like parenthesis:

```
<input onChanged={$=>this.onSomethingChanged("username")} />
```

where `$` is event object (can be replaced by `e` or any other character at your taste).

Comment: This may be a good approach! I like it! I'll wait for other answers, if there is not, I'll accept yours!

Answer (score 0):

No. This is the first argument past into any function. By passing in null you're saying the this is null.

Do this instead.

```
<input onChanged={this.onSomethingChanged.bind(this, "username")} />
```

Comment: If I need to write a lot of binding for this, is there not a shortcut?

Comment: Uhh they're other ways to do this. One is don't use this. Look into closure's instead. Much easier to write/understand IMO.  All you're doing with binding is creating a curry with this, and "username" as default params, you can accomplish this with closures. And avoid using the keyword this, and there would be no need to bind.

Comment: But the problem by using closures (you mean inside onChanged?) is that it will pollute my render method and make it unreadable. Otherwise, if you think of another way, can you provide an example in your answer?

Comment: Are you just calling validate on each field?

Comment: Not all fields, just some of them.

Comment: Are you doing anything with it after validating?

Comment: I'm setting some feedback on the field (validation success, validation failed). Would you like I add some more code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72946/discussion-between-user2734679-and-raito).